# Upgrade 12.04 to 12.10 using startup disk

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, 12.10

I'm trying to upgrade 12.04 to 12.10 using a startup disk, but when I am supposed to choose the type of installation I want, Upgrade option is not available. Can anybody help? I don't want to use Update manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by choosing "Test Ubuntu" instead of "Install Ubuntu", connecting it to the internet then opening "Install Ubuntu 12.10". The upgrade option is now working.